# Typescript, React - Accepting either SFC or Class Component as argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript, so please excuse the trivial question, however I'm trying to write a function that will accept either a Stateless Function Component (SFC) or a Class Component. I thought this might be achieved with a union type. However I am getting an error.

```
const render = (Component: React.StatelessComponent<any> | React.ComponentClass<any>) => {
  // ...
}
```

Error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'StatelessComponent<{}> | ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<{}>'. 
Type 'StatelessComponent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}>'. 
Type 'StatelessComponent<{}>' provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: {} | undefined, context?: any): Component<{}, ComponentState>'.
```

I'm having trouble working out what this error message actually means. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Actual code below, I was trying to strip it back as an example:

index.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { default as Root, Props as RootProps } from './components/Root'

const rootContainer = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement

const render = (Component: React.StatelessComponent<any> | React.ComponentClass<any>) => {
  const props: RootProps = { message: 'Universe' }
  const rootElement: JSX.Element = React.createElement(Component, props)
  const wrapperElement: JSX.Element = React.createElement(AppContainer, undefined, rootElement)
  ReactDOM.render(wrapperElement, rootContainer)
}

render(Root)

if (module && 'hot' in module) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/Root', () => { render(Root) })
}
```

Root.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

export interface Props extends React.Props<any> {
  message?: string
}

const Root: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => (
  <div>Hello { props.message }.</div>
)

Root.defaultProps = {
  message: 'world'
}

export default Root
```

Comment: This error message isn't meant for the code you posted. Please add the code that actually generated this error.

Comment: Which typescript and react versions are you using?

Comment: I copy pasted your code (excluding the hot module stuff), and runs fine on typescript 2.1.0 and react 15.4.1

Comment: Typescript 2.4.1 and React 15.6.1